# How to add a new column attribute in a pandas dataframe using another row that appears before as a heading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sl.No.': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 
                              4: nan, 5: 4.0, 6: 5.0, 7: 6.0},
                   'Location': {0: 'AREA 1', 1: 'Loc A', 2: 'Loc B', 3: 'Loc C',  
                                4: 'AREA 2', 5: 'Loc D', 6: 'Loc E', 7: 'Loc F'},
                   'Total Depth': {0: nan, 1: 5.6, 2: 6.8, 3: 2.9, 
                                   4: nan, 5: 4.3, 6: 6.0, 7: 5.3},
                   'Jan': {0: nan, 1: 2.3, 2: 4.2, 3: 2.1, 
                           4: nan, 5: 2.9, 6: 5.2, 7: 4.3},
                   'Feb': {0: nan, 1: 1.9, 2: 3.8, 3: 2.0, 
                           4: nan, 5: 2.5, 6: 4.6, 7: 3.2}})
```

This produces:

|  | Sl.No. | Location | Total Depth | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | AREA 1 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 1 | Loc A | 5.6 | 2.3 | 1.9 |
| 2 | 2 | Loc B | 6.8 | 4.2 | 3.8 |
| 3 | 3 | Loc C | 2.9 | 2.1 | 2 |
| 4 | nan | AREA 2 | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | 4 | Loc D | 4.3 | 2.9 | 2.5 |
| 6 | 5 | Loc E | 6 | 5.2 | 4.6 |
| 7 | 6 | Loc F | 5.3 | 4.3 | 3.2 |

In the above table AREA 1 and AREA 2 act as the heading for the rows with Sl.No. 1-3 and 4-6 respectively.

I wish to add another column called 'Area' to the dataframe and then delete the these two rows.
That is, I want the following table:

|  | Sl.No. | Area | Location | Total Depth | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | AREA 1 | Loc A | 5.6 | 2.3 | 1.9 |
| 1 | 2 | AREA 1 | Loc B | 6.8 | 4.2 | 3.8 |
| 2 | 3 | AREA 1 | Loc C | 2.9 | 2.1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | AREA 2 | Loc D | 4.3 | 2.9 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 5 | AREA 2 | Loc E | 6 | 5.2 | 4.6 |
| 5 | 6 | AREA 2 | Loc F | 5.3 | 4.3 | 3.2 |

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Removed unnecessary tag `data-science`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whether "Sl.No." column has NaN values or not as a mask on the "Location" column using `where`. Then use `ffill` to fill the NaN values. Finally, drop the rows with NaN values:

```
df['Area'] = df['Location'].where(df['Sl.No.'].isna()).ffill()
df = df.dropna()
```

You can also create Area identifier column using `str.contains` + `cumsum`. Then `groupby` it and apply a lambda that creates a new column "Area" using the first item in the `Location` column for each Location:

```
out = (df.groupby(df['Location'].str.contains('AREA').cumsum())
       .apply(lambda g: g.assign(Area=g['Location'].iat[0]).dropna())
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Sl.No. Location  Total Depth  Jan  Feb    Area
0     1.0    Loc A          5.6  2.3  1.9  AREA 1
1     2.0    Loc B          6.8  4.2  3.8  AREA 1
2     3.0    Loc C          2.9  2.1  2.0  AREA 1
3     4.0    Loc D          4.3  2.9  2.5  AREA 2
4     5.0    Loc E          6.0  5.2  4.6  AREA 2
5     6.0    Loc F          5.3  4.3  3.2  AREA 2
```